# PHP CSS Colour Shuffle array?

Tags: php, jquery, css, shuffle

In a website i have a PHP snippet that on every refresh, certain elements change colour (div's links, text, hover states ect). This works fine but at the moment, on refresh they change to my themes colour by applying them to the the to css where necessary (examples below).

I now have a jQuery function for hover states which animates and all my link:hover states they are included in the colour shuffle. When the colour shuffle is applied though it's the default 'red','blue','green' if you were to put them in the css.

I have had a look online but i am unsure of where else to look as it is working just not on the jQuery snippet so i assume it's something to do with the jQuery function.

PHP at top of header:

```
<?php $colours = array('red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'blue', 'green'); 
shuffle($colours); 
$random = $colours[0]; ?>
```

On the body tag it's echoed as an id:

```
<body id="<?php echo $random; ?>">
```

Link `*<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>*`

And on any div's or elements i want them to change colour before them in the css is #green,#red ect and the colour so if i wanted the 'share class'  to change my css is like this:

```
#green .share {
    color:#79b74c;
}
#red .share {
    color:#900;
}
```

Now this all works apart from my hover shuffle states with the jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // colour rollover navigation
    $(".share").hover(function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({ 'color': "<?php echo $random; ?>" }, 300);
    },function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({ 'color': "#fff" }, 300);
    });
```

It must be something to do with the jQuery as it works well when it's removed, and does work when applied but it's taking the colours from the php as css's default colour hex codes.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to cover all bases - I assume you have a plugin to animate colours?  Fairly sure jQuery doesn't do this on it's own.  Are you getting any JS errors in the dev console?

Comment: I've added the script tag that i am using in my header and no errors in my console! It is working but as of the php at the top it's pulling in the default colours rather than the id css colours like from the body tag.

Comment: Side note: I'd use `$random = $colours[array_rand($colours, 1)];` instead of `shuffle()`.

Comment: Thanks, applied this to my current code. What is the difference of this and shuffle or is it better practice? Thanks

Comment: what happens if you enter `$('.share').animate({'color':'red'},300);` into your console? As it may be that your hover isnt triggering.. the rest looks correct

Comment: When i enter $('.share').animate({'color':'red'},300); (or any other element), it displays as red.This function isn't liking the php!

Comment: You could do this without javascript btw.. is that an option for you? (if it is i will answer with a non-js solution). your jQuery - this is in the php file i take it?

Comment: It works fine for me: http://pastebin.com/emEqSW0F - the only thing the console flagged was the fact that the `$(document).ready(...` wasn't closed (but I'm assuming that's a copy/paste typo on OP's part)

Comment: FYI - the difference between `shuffle` and `array_rand` is that the latter is selecting a single random value from the array rather than having to internally iterate and randomise the entire array.  (in your case the difference is negligible as you are only using a small array)

Comment: Thanks Emissary for the heads up on the shuffle issue. The example you have pasted works the same as mine, but the colour that the hover is showing is css standard 'green', 'red' rather than the style in the css? I am not sure if i need to create a php if function that if blog='pink' display $color = 93F and so on for the rest to pass to to the jQuery variable? I am a novice user for php so apologies if this makes no sense!

Comment: I have edited the code as in created a new script along the lines of JS if statement, I had to ask another question so started a new thread as i may have a solution. Here is the link if anyone wants to follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904993/jquery-if-else-colour-shuffle-passing-a-variable Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about CSS3?

```
  #green .share {
        color:#79b74c;
    }
    #green .share:hover{
        color:#79b74c;
    }
    #red .share {
        color:#900;
    }
    #red .share:hover {
        color:black;
    }
    .share:hover{
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
        -moz-transition:  0.3s;
        -o-transition:  0.3s;
        transition:  0.3s;
    }
```

Comment: Hi there, i am after using JS, sorry even though is a good idea i would like to limit my css to a min, i have a lot of elements that would need adding in to the css and 5 different theme colours.