# Jquery if else colour shuffle (passing a variable)

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement, shuffle

This is regarding this question i asked on this link:[PHP CSS Colour Shuffle array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900452/php-css-colour-shuffle-array)

I have changed and added more code and have a different question hence why i've opened a new thread.

I am using php and jQuery to shuffle colours every time the page is refreshed. At the moment this works fine. But i have a jQuery function where i grab some elements and on a hoverstate show the shuffle colour. Now this does work but it's showing css standard default red,blue,green ect and not even displaying colours for the orange. I have been advised to create a variable and then create an if function and pass the variable through the hover function. Below is what i have so far, im a novice user at jQuery so i am unsure of where i am going wrong or where to go next, can someone guide me to why this is broken? My firebug shows no errors and i think im nearly there! Thanks.

PHP Shuffle colours:

```
<?php
$colours = array('red', 'green', 'blue', 'black');
$blog = $colours[array_rand($colours, 1)];
?>

<body id="<?php echo $blog; ?>">
```

In my css wherever i wanted to show the shuffle colour #green, #red is before the actuallid,class or element and it works! Just the hover states now where i have this jQuery..

// colour rollover navigation

```
var colours = "<?php echo $colours; ?>";


        if(colours == "red"){
           colours = "#600";
        }
        else if(colours == "green"){
           colours = "#363";
        }
        else if(colours == "blue"){
           colours = "#369";
        }
        else if(colours == "black"){
           colours = "#000";
        }

                    //example of some elements that would use the hover effect
        $("#footer .address #breadcrumbs a").hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ 'color': colours }, 300);
        },function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ 'color': "#fff" }, 300);
        });
```

Am i missing some lines in the if else or passing the variable through wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I presume the JS is in script tags on the page.

You can't just `echo` out an array. I'm guessing you meant to `echo` `$blog`. That should pass a single color as string data to be picked up by your `if () {} else {}` statements (should be `switch () { case }` really).

Comment: I've echoed the blog and tried a switch/case statement and still nothing. With the statement in and hovered over, nothing happens. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have it working.

I did some things so not sure exactly what totally fixed it:

-Clear Cache (Google Chrome is a pain for this)

-Changed the variable from Colours to color (both in php and JS)

-When defining the variable in JS i echoed $blog instead of $colour.

I get no errors when this works as well.

Thanks!